# How to submit three forms with one submit button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I have 3 forms I would like to submit with one button:

```
<form id="#formEditUsername">
//Code
</form>

<form id="#formEdituseremail">
//Code
</form>

<form id="#new_password_form">
//Code
</from>

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="btnUpdate">Save</button>
```

I understand that the best way to do this is probably Ajax, but am unsure how I would do this; create two AJAX functions for the first two forms and then call the functions when the third is submitted?

Comment: And can i ask why you want to do this you want to display three forms or submit?

Comment: Collect values from input tags then populate the third form with them and submit.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#btnUpdate").click(function() {
            $.post($("#formEditUsername").attr("action"), $("#formEditUsername").serialize(),
              function() {
                $.post($("#formEdituseremail").attr("action"), $("#formEdituseremail").serialize(),
                  function() {
                    $.post($("#new_password_form").attr("action"), $("#new_password_form").serialize(),
                       function() {
                        alert('All forms submitted');
                      });                
                  });
              });
          });
      });
```

Comment: This may work, but looks like [spaghetti](http://www.computerhope.com/jargon/s/spaghett.htm). Please consider rewriting that in a cleaner way.

Answer (score 0):

As @Jari mentioned, you can simply collect data from first two forms and submit them all together.

Note: this aproach requires input `name` attributes to be **unique** among all three forms.

Simple example of AJAX call:

```
var firstFormData = $("#formEditUsername").serialize();
var secondFormData = $("#formEdituseremail").serialize();
var thirdFormData = $("#new_password_form").serialize();

$.post(
    URL,              // target URL of your choice 
    firstFormData + secondFormData + thirdFormData
);
```

Comment: thanks but the form functions are discrete; I want to submit 3 different forms not concatenate them into one?

Comment: please elaborate further on what processing are you planning on server side. without knowing this it's hard to say which solution is the best for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
<form id="#formEditUsername" class="frmToSubmit" method="post">
//Code
</form>

<form id="#formEdituseremail" class="frmToSubmit" method="post">
//Code
<form>

<form id="#new_password_form" class="frmToSubmit" method="post">
//Code
</from>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#btnUpdate").click(function() {
        $(".frmToSubmit").submit();
    });
});
</script>
```